# Android Studio - failing to install the SDK

Tags: android, sdk

I am trying to install a standard installation of Android Studio.

When I run the programme it begins to download a zip file: android-sdk_r22.6.2-macosx.zip

However it keeps crashing halfway through, connection times out.

So I have simply downloaded the zip directly.

My question is simply, where do I copy this to?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the name of download file or its name is android-sdk_r22.6.2-macosx.zip??

Comment: Hi - yes thats the name.